# Addition in array in JS

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have to do an addition in javascript, with an array like this:

```
[
{name: "toto",note: 2},
{name: "titi",note: 4},
{name: "toto",note: 5}
]
```

I would like to get 2+4+5=11 (better is the average, with 3.6666).

I tried with .reduce, but i can't do it. Any help ?
thanks

Comment: Please show us what you tried with `reduce` that did not work.

Comment: ... what do you mean better is the average?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users  To all the people answering a question that does not show effort... you're not helping

Comment: This question has been asked about a billion times. Please look before you post.

Answer (score 1):

The `.reduce()` way

```js
let data = [
{name: "toto",note: 2},
{name: "titi",note: 4},
{name: "toto",note: 5}
]

let result = data.reduce((a,v) => v.note + a, 0);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a loop *(which is in my test ~50% faster than `reduce()`)* to build the sum:

```
let a = [
{name: "toto",note: 2},
{name: "titi",note: 4},
{name: "toto",note: 5}
];

let sum = 0;
for(var i=0; i< a.length; i++){
    sum += a[i].note;
}

// sum = 11
```

If you want the average:

```
let avg = sum / a.length;
// avg = 3.6666~
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try:

```js
const arr = [
  {name: "toto",note: 2},
  {name: "titi",note: 4},
  {name: "toto",note: 5}
]

const result = arr.reduce((acc, { note }) => acc += note,0)

console.log((result/arr.length).toFixed(4))
```

Answer (score 0):

pretty short code

```
    const data = [
        { name: "toto", note: 2 },
        { name: "titi", note: 4 },
        { name: "toto", note: 5 }
    ];
    const average = data.reduce((a, { note }) => {
        return a + note;
    }, 0) / data.length;
    console.log(average);
```